# Eclipse BIRT not working properly on new mac

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I recently started using the new macbook air (M1 chip Big Sur 11.2.3) and I can't get eclipse BIRT to open properly on it. At first my workspaces were blank and I was unable to click anything and no log files were produced. After deleting and reinstalling birt and my jdk I was able to get the workspace to open, but unable to open reports, and buttons were disappearing unless I hovered over them. It did produce an error log that I have attached here.  I was using java 16 when this log was produced. I thought maybe it was too new of a version for BIRT so I tried java 8, and my workspace is blank again. I have been using eclipse photon. Any thoughts?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.core.gen 4 0 2021-04-12 16:36:31.265
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jpt.dbws.eclipselink.core.gen [521]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.builder; bundle-version="[2.3.0,3.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.builder; bundle-version="2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f"
       org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.builder [752]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.persistence.tools.oracleddl.metadata; version="1.0.0"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.persistence.tools.oracleddl.metadata.visit; version="1.0.0"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.persistence.tools.oracleddl.parser; version="1.0.0"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.persistence.tools.oracleddl.util; version="1.0.0"; resolution:="optional"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.dbws; bundle-version="2.7.1"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.dbws; bundle-version="2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f"
              org.eclipse.persistence.dbws [751]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs; version="2.0.1"; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs.core; version="2.0.1"; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs.ext; version="2.0.1"; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind.annotation; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.ws; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.ws.handler; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.ws.soap; resolution:="optional"
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy; bundle-version="2.7.1"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy; bundle-version="2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f"
                     org.eclipse.persistence.moxy [755]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.bind; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.bind.annotation; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.bind.api; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.codemodel; version="[2.2.11,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.xsom; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.xsom.impl; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.parser; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.tools.xjc; version="[2.2.11,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.tools.xjc.model; version="[2.2.11,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.sun.tools.xjc.outline; version="[2.2.11,3.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.json; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.json.stream; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.validation; version="1.1.0"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.validation.constraints; version="1.1.0"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.validation.groups; version="1.1.0"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.validation.metadata; version="1.1.0"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs; version="2.0.1"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs.core; version="2.0.1"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs.ext; version="2.0.1"; resolution:="optional"
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy; bundle-version="2.7.1"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.persistence.moxy; bundle-version="2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1682)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1555)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It's really frustrating for me not to be able to use BIRT on my Macbook Pro. I've already tried it in a thousand ways, and the only situation as far as it goes is the same one you mention. I have tried all versions of java, birt, eclipse, adoptjdk and none have worked for me.

Comment: So frustrating. I've had to use a remote desktop for all my reporting work. I saw a new release is coming out in June though. Fingers crossed that it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried the following url within the eclipse package manager. It worked for me but the preview is still owed.

```
https://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/snapshot/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the old version I use for Mac 2019 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/file/48028

download link
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/R/eclipse-reporting-neon-R-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tried and with this version Birt run correctly??

This is the old version I use for Mac 2019 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/file/48028

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).